# addChild(object) isn't working, variables are correct, x/y are set

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Following code isn't addchilding a lv1 to the stage for some reason, this is the stage class and is attached to the stage, both classes are correct (triple checked...) and no errors are generated...

```
package  
{
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.*;

    public class TankDrive extends MovieClip
    {
        public var lev1:lv1;

        public function TankDrive() 
        {
            lev1 = new lv1();
            lev1.x = 0;
            lev1.y = 0;
            addChild(lev1);
        }
    }

}
```

Also I checked against other code that worked and found no differences other the specific variable names which I quadruple-checked...

Comment: We need to know 2 things: 1) Is TankDrive your application class? If not, is it being added to the stage? 2) Is there anything in lv1 that would show up on the screen? If the answer to those is "yes", do us a favor and add `trace(stage)` under the addChild and let us know the result.

Comment: Yes, TankDrive is the .fla file, and yes, lv1 would show up on the stage. Learned something, if no errors show and no output is popping up for testing the movie, debug still gives output, for this it is as follows: Attempting to launch and connect to Player using URL [saveing space]
[SWF] C:\Users\BigRed\Desktop\TankDrive\TankDrive.swf - 2801 bytes after decompression
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at lv1()[C:\Users\BigRed\Desktop\TankDrive\lv1.as:12]
 at TankDrive()[C:\Users\BigRed\Desktop\TankDrive\TankDrive.as:12]

Comment: So I just need to figure out what is null and correct it, line 12 is lev1 = new lv1();...  don't know why it is null though... null line in other class is stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keypush);... I do have public function keypush(event:KeyboardEvent):void { } in it...

Comment: Oh, by .fla file i mean .as file (class) connected to the .fla file, i use the same name for both with a different extension for simplicity.

Comment: It says `at lv1()` this means an error in inside the `lv1()` function, not here. Please provide code for lv1, as well as review what instances are placed on a `lv1` symbol at design time.

Comment: are you sure the width and the height of the lev1 are not 0 ?

Comment: Yes. They are the same size as the stage. If they were 0 I wouldn't see it when I was editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your imports try adding the lv1.as file and see if it helps kill that null error.

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.*;
import lv1; //imports the lv1.as file

public class TankDrive extends MovieClip
    {
        public var lev1:lv1;

        public function TankDrive() 
        {
            lev1 = new lv1();
            lev1.x = 0;
            lev1.y = 0;
            addChild(lev1);
        }
    }
```

EDIT TWO ------------ After re-reading comments -----------

> null line in other class is
>   stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keypush);... I do have
>   public function keypush(event:KeyboardEvent):void { } in it...

Get rid of `stage.` and only just have `addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keypush);`
The line `addChild(lev1);` in TankDrive already gives contents of lv1 some access to stage so in lv1 just writing addChild is enough.

NOTE: This is true for most eventListeners (mouse/timers etc) and also display objects. 
When you need to explicitly access the stage (especially for stage+keyboard listeners) you must setup your lv1.as like so:

1. Add a listener to check for when the stage is available to lv1 contents.
2. If available then get entire stage to listen for keyboard controls.

   ```
   public function lv1() {
   addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageAvailable);
   //Your other code here...
   }

   private function stageAvailable(e:Event):void {
   trace("(LV1.AS): ADDED_TO_STAGE was successful");
   removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageAvailable);
   stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keypush);
   //Your other keyboard listeners code...
   }
   ```

Comment: Changed Nothing at all. I learned something today though, I'm not sure where you would do this unless for some reason you needed a class for something you were drawing with code.

Comment: Ok. I wrote that earlier from memory but after testing now in Flash it works. So why not for you? Check my "edit two" answer and let me know how it goes...

Comment: Thanks, that was a simple error: don't add event listeners to stage, add them to nothing...

Comment: Except now my addEventLIsteners aren't working, strage that adding them to stage would work in one class but not another, is their any import so i can use stage.addEventListener or somethign else I should add my listeners to so they work?

Comment: Sorry for delay.. I've extended "Edit two" to include a fix for your keyboard listeners. As for your questionss, 1) It depends on your app/code setup whether you addChild to stage or nothing. I was just answering a specific error you had. 2) Well actually eventListeners work fine just only in this case you have a focus issue (stage listening to keyboard). If you gave your "actor" a buttonMode = true then clicked on it before using k/board it would run the keypush function because at that moment it's in focus after mouse click. That said the ADDED_TO_STAGE code will fix your k/board problem.

Comment: Ok, I asked in gdr (game development room) and have come up with another solution of trying to move it to the document class and somehow share variables, if I can't get that to work i'll try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must inherit lev1 class from DisplayObject or any class inherited from DisplayObject (eg. Sprite, MovieClip etc). addChild method accepts only DisplayObject instances.

Comment: I used to think that also but you can definately addChild other classes!! I think it gives their Vars and DisplayObjects access to the main stage (if addChild is done in main document code)

Comment: Does that mean 'public class lv1 extends MovieClip'? Could you restate this with informal wording?

Comment: Yes, "public class lv1 extends MovieClip" is ok

Comment: Ok, got it from other guy, but another problem. (See comments to other question)